# How to Group Rows With Same Values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a `DataFrame` `df` like this :

```
     user_id  movie_id  rating
32236   1        1        5
23171   1        2        3
83307   1        3        4
62631   1        4        3
47638   1        5        3
26184   2        1        4
1333    5        1        4
172     5        2        3
54487   6        1        4
52430   7        4        5
18504   10       1        4
4617    10       4        4
```

I want `df` to be grouped randomly based on `user_id`, and each group with identical amounts of `user_id`(if can't be divided equally, at least with similar amounts of `user_id`), but without merging the `user_id` rows.

e.g. divided with 2 `user_id` in each group

```
     user_id  movie_id  rating
32236   1        1        5
23171   1        2        3
83307   1        3        4
62631   1        4        3
47638   1        5        3
52430   7        4        5

     user_id  movie_id  rating
26184   2        1        4
18504   10       1        4
4617    10       4        4

     user_id  movie_id  rating
1333    5        1        4
172     5        2        3
54487   6        1        4
```

I've written a method `group(df, n)` :

```
def group(df, n) :
    shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
    result = np.array_split(shuffled, n) 

    dict = {}
    for i, part in enumerate(result):
        dict['df_'+str(i+1)] = part

    return dict
```

But it doesn't work with identical numbers appearing in multiple rows like `df`. And I can only set how many groups to be divided to, not how many `user_id` in each divided group.

How to divide `df` into groups based on `user_id`, and each group with selected amounts of `user_id` like I mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

First, get the unique user IDs and randomly permute them:

`uniques = np.random.permutation(df['user_id'].unique())`

Split the unique IDs (assuming 2 IDs per split):

`splits = np.array_split(uniques, len(uniques) // 2)`

Define a function that will group rows based on the value of the index:

```
def grouper(value):
    return np.argmax([value in split for split in splits])
```

And use it:

```
for group in df.set_index('user_id').groupby(grouper):
    print(group)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can use:

```
d={'df'+str(e):df[df.user_id.isin(i)] for e,i in 
    enumerate(np.array_split(np.random.permutation(df.user_id.unique()),
                                        len(df.user_id.unique())/2))}
```

**Output**

```
{'df0':        user_id  movie_id  rating
 26184        2         1       4
 18504       10         1       4
 4617        10         4       4, 'df1':        user_id  movie_id  rating
 32236        1         1       5
 23171        1         2       3
 83307        1         3       4
 62631        1         4       3
 47638        1         5       3
 52430        7         4       5, 'df2':        user_id  movie_id  rating
 1333         5         1       4
 172          5         2       3
 54487        6         1       4}
```

you can call each key in this dict:

```
print(d['df1'])

       user_id  movie_id  rating
32236        1         1       5
23171        1         2       3
83307        1         3       4
62631        1         4       3
47638        1         5       3
52430        7         4       5
```